# how to fix java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=225; regionStart=4; regionLength=-2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, substring

this is my error:

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.yasht.recyclerviewrss, PID: 4097
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

```
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=225; regionStart=4; regionLength=-2
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at com.example.yasht.recyclerviewrss.m_Rss.RssParser.parseRSS(RssParser.java:107)
    at com.example.yasht.recyclerviewrss.m_Rss.RssParser.doInBackground(RssParser.java:47)
    at com.example.yasht.recyclerviewrss.m_Rss.RssParser.doInBackground(RssParser.java:21)`
```

my source where error is occured :

```
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                    if(!isSiteMeta)
                    {
                        if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {
                            article.setTitle(tagValue);
                        }else if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
                        {
                            String desc=tagValue;

                            //EXTRACT IMAGE FROM DESC
                            // error in this line =>  
                             String 
 imageUrl=desc.substring(desc.indexOf("src=")+5,desc.indexOf("jpg")+3);
                            article.setImageurl(imageUrl);`
```

Comment: why are you not xml parsing it into an object?

If you just want to do it this way then I would check a few things before I do a substring. 

if (desc.indexOf("src=") > 0 && desc.indexOf("jpg") > desc indexOf("src") + 5).... etc

Answer (score 0):

It seems `jpg` is not there in `desc` so `desc.indexOf("jpg")` returns `-1` and `+3` gives `-2`!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this.

1. Create a XSD for the XML
   If you use Intellij you can create XSD from XML
2. Use JAXB to create the mapped object
   You can put the XSD into your resource folder and with JAXB maven plugin it will generate the classes for you when you build your maven project.

> ```
> <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>0.12.3</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>generate</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
> ```

The classes get generated in

[image: folder where you find generated sources]

3. Parse the XML into an Object. 
   Just copy these classes into your project from the xjc and all you need to do is:-

> ```
> JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MessageType.class, ObjectFactory.class);
> Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
> Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
> JAXBElement<MessageType> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, MessageType.class);
> ```

This approach will be far better than trying to parse a XML doc yourself.

if you had to do it manually

If you just want to do it the way you have done it then I would check a few things before I do a substring.

```
if (desc.indexOf("src=") > 0 && desc.indexOf("jpg") > desc indexOf("src") + 5) {
....
}
```